# Two if statements for one block PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to have two `if` statements in a single block like this:

```
$jmsa = "m";
$hsma = "c";

if($u = $jmsa), if($p = $hsma) {
    header('Location: klo.php');
}else{/* [...] */ }
```

But idk how to do this

Please help! All insight is appreciated.

Comment: `if($u = $jmsa && $p = $hsma)` or use a  `||` also you know that this is every time true, maybe you want to use `==`?

Comment: Use the and operator (`&&`)? `if ($u == $jmsa && $p == $hsma)` ... You also want to use `==`, and **not** `=`, as the later is for assignment, not comparison (this is a common mistake, especially for new programmers, so keep an eye out for it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if `$u` is equal to `$jmsa` **and**  `$p` is equal to `$hsma`

```
if($u == $jsma && $p == $hsma){
```

And

> if `$u` is equal to `$jmsa` **or**  `$p` is equal to `$hsma`

```
if($u == $jsma || $p == $hsma){
```

Check the **bold** part.

Note `||` means `or` and `&&` means `and`. But they *differ* in [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: It is notable, that for beginners, you may substitute `||` with the word `or` and `&&` may be substituted with the word `and` -- just for your own readability purposes.

Comment: @rm-vanda `and` & `&&` do have different precedence, though. Usually, you can just use `and` fine (it only matters if you are doing assignment in your statements, which is a bad idea IMHO)... I personally prefer `and` as well, but many style guides (PHP people love long style guides) forbid it...

Answer (score 1):

You can use && operator and == for condition checking
= is used as assignment operator

```
        $jmsa = "m";
        $hsma = "c";

        if($u == $jmsa && $p == $hsma) {
        header('Location: klo.php');
        }else{}
```